# Draw 4-way set associative mapping

Tags: caching, memory, set, mapping, associative

can you help me about this? I tried that about draw something but i thought it was wrong. Thats why im asking to you.
**QUESTION**:
Assume you have 32-bit processor with 4-way set associative 16KB cache memory . Line of
the cache memory has length: 4 words 32-bits each. Make drawing like that example in
such circumstances.

**EXAMPLE**
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q17oJ.png)

its very hard to draw and i didnt even understand how can i do th